# how to show array name in textview getting from json file

Tags: android

below is my code i use two  json file one contain data second contain date problem is only in second json file i want to first check if date is exist in json file which i paste below then show json array"title" of that date in textview in post onPostExecute   just check this line
if (Vacation_Date.contains(mydate)) { is match then show json array"title" of that date in textview in onPostExecute  how to do that???

```
   static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> school_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> menu_name = new ArrayList<String>();

static ArrayList<String> dish_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> day = new ArrayList<String>();




static ArrayList<Long> Vacation_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Vacation_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Vacation_Date = new ArrayList<String>();



  public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        getDataTask(){
            if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
                txtAlert.setVisibility(8);

            }
        }

        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            parseJSONData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            prgLoading.setVisibility(8);

            if((Category_ID.size() > 0) || IOConnect == 0){

                listCategory.setAdapter(cla);


                if (message.equals("weekly")) {

                    menu_nametxt.setText(mVal2);
                    listCategory.setVisibility(0);

                } else if (message.equals("error")){
                    menu_nametxt
                    .setText("No menu available on this date! ");
                    listCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }   


                else if (message.equals("holiday")){
                    menu_nametxt.setText(mVal2);
//menu_nametxt.setText(mVal2); not show title value on textview why????
                    listCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }   





            }else{
                txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
                menu_nametxt.setText("");
                listCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }





                public void parseJSONData() {


    try {

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line;
        }

        JSONObject json3 = new JSONObject(str2);

        status = json3.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {

            JSONArray school = json3.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int k = 0; k < school.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) school.getJSONObject(k);
                Vacation_ID.add((long) k);

                Vacation_Date.add(jb.getString("date"));

            }

        }

        else {

        }

        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

        status = json2.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {

            if (Vacation_Date.contains(mydate)) {
                message = "holiday";

                JSONObject json4 = new JSONObject(str2);

                status = json4.getString("status");
                if (status.equals("1")) {

                JSONArray school = json4.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int k = 0; k < school.length(); k++) {
        JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) school.getJSONObject(k);
            Vacation_ID.add((long) k);

            String[] mVal = new String[school.length()];

    mVal[k] = school.getJSONObject(k).getString("title");

                mVal2 = mVal[0];

                    }

                }


     {"status":1,
   "data":
   [
    {"id":"1",
   "title":"abc",
  "date":"2013-09-29"},

   {"id":"2",
      "title":"abc1",
     "date":"2013-09-25"},

     {"id":"3",
    "title":"abc",
    "date":"2013-10-05"},

    {"id":"4",
     "title":"abc1",
    "date":"2013-09-27"}]
      }
```

Comment: You'll have more luck getting an answer if you use sentences.

Comment: now check i reduce my code just tell me if this linematch
if (Vacation_Date.contains(mydate))  how i will get"title" of match value from json file and show in textview??